# Exception NON-Handling : Ignoring exceptions without try catch

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

This might be a stupid question since i'm not really used to working with javascript.

I have a group of instructions and want to execute them without interruption, and without using try...catch. For instance, let consider this :

```
do_stuff_A();
do_stuff_B();
do_stuff_C();
...
```

If *do_stuff_A()* fails, I want *do_stuff_B()* to be executed and so on, without interruption, without doing this :

```
try { do_stuff_A(); }
catch { };
try { do_stuff_A(); }
catch { };
...
```

Because if I do it this way :

```
try {
  do_stuff_A(); // if this fails
  do_stuff_B(); // this won't be executed
  do_stuff_C();
  ...
} catch {
   // Never mind
}
```

Is there a magic tool to do it like this :

```
ignore_exceptions {
  do_stuff_A();
  do_stuff_B();
  do_stuff_C();
  ...
}
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: you can write a wrapper function that invokes the passed function with the passed arguments, but inside a try/catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While its a [bad practice to swallow exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding), I assume you have a good reason for that.

You could write a wrapper function to make it less verbose:

```
function runAndIgnoreExceptions(f) {
 try{
    return f();
 } catch(e){}
}

runAndIgnoreExceptions(do_stuff_A);
runAndIgnoreExceptions(do_stuff_B);
runAndIgnoreExceptions(do_stuff_C);
```

Depending up on your use case, you might want to prefer to use a `finally`-block.
This way the finally block is always executed, but the exception is raised from a caller point of view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer user3246431. I agree it's a nasty practice but in my case i don't really mind :-)